# will iOS accept external payment for a magazine subsription

Tags: ios, paypal, payment

I'm designing a magazine app with subscription in app.
The rules at Apple seem confusing about when you can and can't use IAP.

Is there a way to use paypal or Stripe for this kind of payments or will my app be rejected for not using IAP.

are external payment platforms only for physical goods ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app will be rejected if it points to an external link to make payment.
You must use In-App purchase for anything related to payment from the App itself.

Comment: But I saw a few applications doing this without problem.

Comment: If your magazine is a hard copy then you can do the subscription without  In-App purchase.